# change uipicker/ uidatetimepicker font , iphone / objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

How to change the font size and style of the uipicker view of iphone. can any one suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In UIPickerView's delegate you can implement `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` method and return UILabel object from it with any font you want (and other parameters) specified.